# Can this STI structure be achieved in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sti

I want to have these models:

```
AbstractArticle 
Article < AbstractArticle
FeaturedArticle < AbstractArticle
```

I want the name of the database table to be `articles` and not `abstract_articles`. (As the convention suggests)

Is this possible with Rails? How can I tell my base model to use a different table? Will STI still work even though the table name does not follow the convention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

```
class AbstractArticle <  ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name :articles
end
```

http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/howtouselegacyschemas#using_set_table_name_for_table_names_outside_the_rails_convention